# Floating divs Nav & Content Not floating side by side

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have 2 `div` elements: A left Column for my *navigation menu*, and a *main content* `div` with the main content.

Previously I was aligning them like this:

```
#leftnav {
  float: left;
  width: 19vw;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  left: 19vw;
  width: 81%;
}
```

This was all good until the window got too small, so the main content would start to shrink beyond its content??? Either way, I decided to alter the code to float the *navigation menu* and *main content* side by side with the contentt at `width: auto`. But no matter what I try, the *main content* `div` will not position itself automatically next to the left *nav*. Instead, it overlaps the left *nav* column.

I think the code should provide you with the right information. I will try to add a JFiddle also..

```
body{
padding:0%;
margin:0%;
width:100%;
height:850px;
font-size:16px;
}


.mainwrap{ 
position:relative; 
top:6px; 
left:5px;
width:100%; 
height:100%; 

}

.left{
position:relative;
top:0.2%;
width:18vw; 
height:auto;
float:left;
padding-left:.5vw;
padding-right:.5vw;
margin-right:10px;
background:#f4f4f4;
border-left:1px solid #ddd;
border-right:1px solid #ddd;
font-size:1em;

}



    #centralcolumn{
    position:relative;
    top:0%; 
    width:auto; 
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    background: #aaa;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    border-right:1px solid #000;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #bbb; 

        }


<body>
<div class="mainwrap">


<div class="left">

<div class='links1'>
<a href="">About Links</a><br><br>
<a href="">Links Forums</a><br><br>
<a href="">Best-of-Links</a><br><br>
<a href="">Links YouTube</a><br><br>
</div>




<div id="centralcolumn"></div>


</div>

<body>
```

See the fiddle, the `div`s do not float side by side. It is important that the *content* `div` has is automatically scalable to the window - hence: `width: auto`.

Any ideas about why the `div`s are not floating correctly? Many thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/kxvhqcy9/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `width` to `#centralcolumn` id and give `box-sizing:border-box` to whole site. It consists of: margins, borders, padding, and the actual content.

```css
html {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 850px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.mainwrap {
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.left {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.2%;
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  padding-left: .5vw;
  padding-right: .5vw;
  margin-right: 2%;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}
#centralcolumn {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  background: #aaa;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
  width:78%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="mainwrap">
    <div class="left">
      <div class='links1'>
        <a href="">About LinkD</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="">LinkD Forums</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="">Best-of-LinkD</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="">LinkD YouTube</a>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content# mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content
    </div>
    <div id="centralcolumn">
      mixed content , mixed contentmixed content , mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content
    </div>
  </div>
  <body>
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks, ankita patel. , its working. im just hoping i donnot run ito previous problems... But thanks mate. much appreciated.

Comment: Very, close, but the right div still overlaps the left when scaling the window size.. i will try to adjust the margins. ect.

Comment: see fiddle and relocate size of window. and look at the right div overlap..  https://jsfiddle.net/kxvhqcy9/4/

Comment: Sir, you have outdone yourself... It works perfectly. Thank you... i will investigate your proposals... Much appreiciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flex` as well.

```css
body {
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 850px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.mainwrap {
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mainwrap {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.2%;
  width: 18vw;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  padding-left: .5vw;
  padding-right: .5vw;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}

#centralcolumn {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  background: #aaa;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="mainwrap">


    <div class="left">

      <div class='links1'>
        <a href="">About LinkD</a><br><br>
        <a href="">LinkD Forums</a><br><br>
        <a href="">Best-of-LinkD</a><br><br>
        <a href="">LinkD YouTube</a><br><br>
      </div>
      mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content# mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content
    </div>


    <div id="centralcolumn">

      mixed content , mixed contentmixed content , mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content mixed content , mixed content
    </div>




  </div>

  <body>
```

Comment: Thank you v.much ankita patel, Your solution works wonders... The webkit box sizing made all the difference. And yes the inline flex also does the same.. Many thanks.